# What disassembler do you recommend?

Tags: winapi, assembly

I'm into hacking challenges (like rankk.com) and some of the challenges require disassembly and little modifications of PE files.

I'm looking for a disassembler/debugger that is able to dump the strings, walk the assembler code and allow modifications.

My knowledge in this field is very limited so I'm looking for something relatively easy to use and preferably free.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IDA, nothing else comes even close.
[IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/)

Comment: Like you said, nothing touches IDA Pro

Answer (score 5):

I like [OllyDbg.](http://www.ollydbg.de/) (with a good [companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764574817) :)

Answer (score 2):

IDA Pro has a nice graph for better understanding of the code flow and the disassembler is amazing. Although i use OllyDbg as JIT debugger and general debugger for MASM.

Answer (score 1):

IDA also has a free version now of their previous version. For light or introductory reversing or getting started it's a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

IDA Pro for common cases, SoftIce for special cases (for example when you need to reverse highly protected application, you can use special SoftIce plugins and so on). I was an experienced cracker in student years :)