# What tools are best for learning reverse engineering

Tags: com, reverse-engineering

I am starting to learn reverse engineering and wanted to know what tools people are using and what the pros and cons are to each.  I have been using .Net Reflector to reverse engineer .Net apps but I also have to work with old COM dlls and it would be great to figure out what they are doing.  Many of the developers who wrote them didn't check the code into source control and the binaries are out on the production servers.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Reverse engineering is like engineering- There are different tools for different domains and abstraction layers. Can you elaborate what you're trying to do ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912750/what-dissasembler-do-you-recomend/912775#912775

Comment: We actually do have some source code for the dlls but we are in dll hell and don't know which dll matches which version of the sourcecode.  We would like to make modifications to the source we have but can't be sure stuff isn't missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Ollydbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/) is a great free tool for analyzing and debugging native apps and DLLs. Also the various tools from [HeavenTools](http://www.heaventools.com/) are really useful. Native code is not quite as easy as reversing .NET, you'll generally need a solid foundation in x86 assembly language to get very far.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring too reverse engineering in general you might also check out tools like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) for network protocol sniffing

Answer (score 1):

Also, there's a fairly comprehensive freely available wikibook on [Reverse Engineering](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Reverse_Engineering).

Answer (score 0):

If you have symbols for your COM dlls, you can set breakpoints on the interface implementations and set through the disassembly in [NTSD](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx).

Answer (score 0):

IDA Pro is an interactive disassembler. Which work both with .NET and native executables. It has a decompiler plugin (HexRays). Also it has a debugger. It is very expensive but there's a free version.